# EmberJS - register precompiled handlebars template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

For my EmberJS app, I precompile all of my handlebars templates, so they are being loaded as straight Javascript files.

The problem is that these precompiled templates are not making their way into the Ember container like I thought that they would - I get the following error when I specify a template for my view.

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: You specified the templateName "application" for <MyApp.ApplicationView:ember164>, but it did not exist.
```

Here is my view code.

```
window.MyApp.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
   templateName: 'application'
});
```

I stepped through the execution and saw that the views do not exist in the Ember container. Is there something special I need to do to register precompiled templates with the container? If so, how?

Edit: I've been compiling the templates with the handlebars npm package.

Comment: What are you using to precompile your templates?

Comment: And, are you injecting the templates before your app loads? Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/Xsbhk/) that shows where you should pre-load.

Comment: I've just been using the npm handlebars package. Is there a special ember one I need to use??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the npm handlebars compiler does indeed compile them correctly, you still need to register them with Ember in order for them to load correctly. You can do one of the following:

- Manually load them with Ember.TEMPLATES['sometemplate'] = COMPILED TEMPLATE. This works but becomes something of a pain.
- Use a special compiler like npm ember-precompile, which will compile them in such a way that the compiled templates are automatically registered in the Ember template container.

Answer (score 3):

Templates are looked up on `Ember.TEMPLATES` (which is just a hash with the template name as the key)

So when your example `ApplicationView` is executed it will look for the template in `Ember.TEMPLATES['application']`

Comment: Yes, I know that - I'm asking what I need to do to load the compiled templates into that container. They aren't getting in there!

Comment: You have to manually put them there as part of the pre-compiling process.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a Ruby/Guard-based solution, check out my gist here: https://gist.github.com/perlun/5286391

Use it like this from your Guardfile:

```
guard 'ember_handlebars',
    :input => 'app/handlebars_templates',
    :output => 'app/handlebars_compiled',
    :remove_prefix => 'app/handlebars_templates/' do
  watch(%r{app/handlebars_templates/(.+\.handlebars)})
end
```

```